# How can I stack equations using estout?

Tags: stata

I am creating a summary statistics table using the *community-contributed* command `estout`.

The code looks like this:

```
sysuse auto, clear
eststo clear
eststo: estpost ttest price mpg weight headroom trunk if rep78 ==3, by(foreign)
eststo: estpost ttest price mpg weight headroom trunk if rep78 ==4, by(foreign)
estout, cells("mu_1 mu_2 b(star)")
```

The result looks as follows:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                 est1                                      est2                             
                 mu_1         mu_2            b            mu_1         mu_2            b   
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
price        6607.074     4828.667     1778.407        5881.556     6261.444    -379.8889   
mpg                19     23.33333    -4.333333        18.44444     24.88889    -6.444444** 
weight       3442.222         2010     1432.222***     3532.222     2207.778     1324.444***
headroom     3.222222     2.666667     .5555556        3.444444          2.5     .9444444*  
trunk        15.59259     12.33333     3.259259        16.66667     10.33333     6.333333** 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to know how I could stack `est1` and `est2` on top of each other.

Answer (score 2):

The command `estout` *cannot* automatically stack results from stored estimates. Consequently, the use of `eststo` is redundant. In this case, the easiest way to obtain the desired output is to simply create two matrices with the results and stack one on top of the other.

For example:

```
sysuse auto, clear

matrix A = J(5, 3, .)

local i 0
foreach var of varlist price mpg weight headroom trunk {
    local ++i
    ttest `var'  if rep78 == 3, by(foreign)
    matrix A[`i', 1] = r(mu_1)
    matrix A[`i', 2] = r(mu_2)
    matrix A[`i', 3] = r(mu_1) - r(mu_2)
    local matnamesA `matnamesA' "rep78==3:`var'"
}

matrix rownames A = `matnamesA'

matrix B = J(5, 3, .)

local i 0
foreach var of varlist price mpg weight headroom trunk {
    local ++i
    ttest `var'  if rep78 == 4, by(foreign)
    matrix B[`i', 1] = r(mu_1)
    matrix B[`i', 2] = r(mu_2)
    matrix B[`i', 3] = r(mu_1) - r(mu_2)
    local matnamesB `matnamesB' "rep78==4:`var'"
}

matrix rownames B = `matnamesB'

matrix C = A \ B
```

```
esttab matrix(C), nomtitles collabels("mu_1" "mu_2" "diff")

---------------------------------------------------
                     mu_1         mu_2         diff
---------------------------------------------------
rep78==3                                            
price            6607.074     4828.667     1778.407
mpg                    19     23.33333    -4.333333
weight           3442.222         2010     1432.222
headroom         3.222222     2.666667     .5555556
trunk            15.59259     12.33333     3.259259
---------------------------------------------------
rep78==4                                            
price            5881.556     6261.444    -379.8889
mpg              18.44444     24.88889    -6.444444
weight           3532.222     2207.778     1324.444
headroom         3.444444          2.5     .9444444
trunk            16.66667     10.33333     6.333333
---------------------------------------------------
```